# in UsersController#create, User.new(params[:user]) return an empty User (params looks good)

Tags: activerecord, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm kind of new to Rails 3.1. and I'm facing an issue only in my production env with my Signup form (actually, it's more about the controller).

Here is the code in User

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

[...]

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  logger.info "value of login in param : #{params[:user][:login]}" #-> log the actual login
  logger.info "value of login : #{@user.login}"                    #-> log empty
  @user.admin = false
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = t('flash.notice.user.create.valid')
    redirect_back_or_default root_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = t('flash.notice.user.create.invalid')
    render :action => :new
  end
 end
end
```

Also, the controller logs show that the params hash is good

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"QwOqmp0CT/d4mmC1yiLT4uZjP9bNDhbUXHanCQy5ZrA=", 
  "user"=>{"login"=>"myLogin", 
           "email"=>"t.r@gmail.com", 
           "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
           "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

My login form works as expected (already created users are able to sign in)

Again, this only happens in production.

EDIT: Here is my User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic

  #== Callbacks
  before_create :set_defaults

  attr_accessible :avatar     ##### EDIT: TO FIX THE ISSUE, ADD THE OTHER FIELDS AS WELL

  protected

  def set_defaults
    self.total_1 = self.total_2 = self.total_3 = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Any chance you're using `attr_accessible` in your `User` model and not including `login` in the list? Is it only the `login` field that's empty, or are all the fields empty? If you post your `User` model it may give us more info

Comment: I added the model to my question. My model is pretty simple. The only noticeable thing is the Auth_logic stuff. All my fields are empty, not just the login. It's so weird because it happens only in production env, not on the dev env.

Comment: You answered my question. I have paperclip that saves the user's avatar and that requires attr_accessible. I naively only added this field to the list, without knowing it was a white list for mass assignation. I fixed it. Thank you so much, you saved my coding night session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to memorialize the answer from the comments above:

Normally you can use mass assignment to set fields on a model, but when you use `attr_accessible`, you are then limited to only mass assigning those fields. So stuff like `User.new(params[:user])` won't work; instead, you'd have to do:

```
@user = User.new
@user.login = params[:user][:login]
# ...etc.
@user.save
```

Simple add your fields to the `attr_accessible` list and you can go back to mass assignment.

Comment: thanks. To avoid putting all the fields in the attr_accessible list, I used attr_protected with one field I know will (and should) not be mass-assigned (:admin). It's easier from a maintenance perspective.