# "user_"prefixing of parameters prevents form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following [Ryan Bates' Multistep Forms cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms?view=comments) but my parameters are prefixed with "user_". So password becomes user_password, etc. During user creation, the teamname attribute doesn't get validated. I suppose this is due to the user_ prefix and again I suppose it is due to the deep_merge due to its default prefixing or use of "user_params" and tried to add "{:knockout_prefix => 'user_'}" but it didn't worked.

users/new.html.erb begins with a routine "<%= form_for @user do |f| %>" and includes "<%= render "#{@user.current_step}_step", :f => f %>". The steps include fields like "<%= f.text_field :email %>", not "user_email" or anything else.

users_controller.rb contains a create function:

```
def create
  session[:user_params].deep_merge!(params[:user]) if params[:user]
  @user = User.new(session[:user_params])
  @user.current_step = session[:user_step]
  ...@user.save...(rest of the code omitted)
end
```

models/user.rb contains:

```
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  ..several validation codes according to steps..
```

And the web page source is:

```
<input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
```

Are there any guesses why this prefixing is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in ["in UsersController#create, User.new(params[:user]) return an empty User (params looks good)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024343/in-userscontrollercreate-user-newparamsuser-return-an-empty-user-params). In his answer, Dylan Markow states that:

> you can use mass assignment to set fields on a model, but when attr_accessible is used, you are limited to only mass assigning fields in the attr_accessible line.

So I added all the user parameters to the attr_accessible option, and the validations worked.